# Automation w/Google Pay

Tags: automation, google-pay

Is it possible to automate a check out process using Google Pay as the FOP?

Being told by automation team it's not possible due to:  Google Pay requires being signed into a google account (that has google pay enabled).  And, there is no way to do this with automated tests.